# Adding a template to a class, that's being used in a multiset

Tags: c++, list, function, templates

The fix for this is probably very simple, but I cannot find the answer. An answer will be rewarded with my thanks and my tears.

Basically the below code works just fine without the template (with the T's as primitives of course) but once I add the template, it says my argument list is missing. I figured this has to do with declaring , but these functions are not using scope resolution, at least not in a way I'm familiar with. How do I get this to work?

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T s, int i) : Data(s), pri(i) {}

    //Overload the relational operator so that the priority is compared.
    bool operator < (const Foo<T>& n) const { return n.pri < pri; }
    T getData() { return Data; }
    int getId() { return pri; }

private:
    T Data;
    int pri;
};
```

This is main

```
int main(void)
{
    set<Foo> s; //These should actually be multiset, but was trying to get it to
    s.insert(Foo("C++", 9)); //work as a set before jumping to multiset
    s.insert(Foo("Is ", 7));
    s.insert(Foo("Fun ", 3));

    set<Foo>::iterator p;
    for (p = s.begin(); p != s.end(); p++)
    {
        Foo n = *p;
        cout << "Id: " << n.getId() << "\t Data: " << n.getData() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you're curious, the program is supposed to take a string(or other type) along with a priority and sort the priority, the program isn't complete, but I'm supposed to use this Class in my program, but I'm tripped up over in converting it into a template.

Comment: `Foo n = *p;` The template class requires a template argument?

Comment: Note that compiler errors in C++ tell you what *line* the error occurred on.  Look for the first mention of *your* code in the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` expect a **type**.

Before the introduction of the template part, `Foo` was a type.

Now that is a template class, `Foo` isn't a type anymore. `Foo<int>` is a type; `Foo<std::string>` is a type; not `Foo`.

So

```
std::set<Foo<int>> s;
```

can work,

```
std::set<Foo> s;
```

give an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `class Foo {};`, `Foo` is the name of a class. However, when you declare `template <class T> class Foo {};`, `Foo` is the name of a *template.* **A template is not a class:** it's a recipe for creating classes. Classes such as `Foo<int>` or `Foo<char>`.

It seems you want to store `std::string`s in your `Foo`s in the set, which means the code should look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    set<Foo<string>> s; //These should actually be multiset, but was trying to get it to
    s.insert(Foo<string>("C++", 9)); //work as a set before jumping to multiset
    s.insert(Foo<string>("Is ", 7));
    s.insert(Foo<string>("Fun ", 3));

    set<Foo<string>>::iterator p;
    for (p = s.begin(); p != s.end(); p++)
    {
        Foo<string> n = *p;
        cout << "Id: " << n.getId() << "\t Data: " << n.getData() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```